# How to power iOS device off

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8

Yes. I actually think that what I am asking is impossible but I'd like to know if you have any idea how to power the iPhone off with swift or objective c code, or at least enter the airplane mode.

Comment: @MattBall no because i would like to turn it off instead, unless it is impossible

Comment: The only possibility open to you is to drain the battery really fast, for example by simultaneously doing high performance CPU & GPU operations. Still, it won't be within minutes :)

Comment: @Sulthan the point is that I want to do so without spending any battery

Comment: It might be also possible to exploit the system to trigger a restart but turning off the device is impossible on a not-jailbroken device.

Comment: @Sulthan in case it is jailbroken?? Is there any way?

Comment: @JuanRocamonde iOS is essentially a Unix system. There should be a `shutdown` command somewhere. On a jailbroken device, you can just call exec from the app and execute it. I don't have a jailbroken device myself so I can't check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with the Public APIs provided by apple. This may be done using the unreleased Private APIs.
But According to Apple's policy, usage of any Private APIs will lead to rejection of App from App Store.